# Download link to Umlet plugin for Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

Can anyone provide me the link to download Umlet plugin into Eclipse Luna?

I already installed Umlet onto my computer, however it doesn't have any features or plugin folders as described in other answers. I also couldn't find any import option to attach it to Eclipse.

When trying to install it using the ".jar" file as an archive in eclipse, it gives me the error message `no software site found at ...`

Comment: i found a helpful link and hints to download umlet and install it to eclipse
here it is:
http://tipsthoughtsnotes.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/umlet-eclipse-plugin-how-to-install-standalone-and-eclipse-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

Choose the latest version of the plugin jar using this link http://www.umlet.com/changes.htm, put it in eclipse/dropins folder and restart eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, i actually ran into  this link:http://tipsthoughtsnotes.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/umlet-eclipse-plugin-how-to-install-standalone-and-eclipse-plugin/ and finally got to download it.
UMLET is working fine for now. thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a guide for installing the umlet plugin in Eclipse:

[Guide to Umlet plugin](https://code-use.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-install-umlet-plugin-for-eclipse.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/32326511)